# Error in R with highcharter library

Tags: r, plot, highcharts, data-mining

I have a problem with this code , what is wrong with this code ?

```
library(highcharter)
hchart(mtcars,x=mpg,y=disp)
```

and the results is this :

```
Error: !is.null(type) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

The interface for this package doesn't seem very intuitive (and that error needs better handling) but try:

```
hchart(mtcars, "scatter", x=mpg, y=disp)
```

The [highcharter docs for hchart](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/hchart.html) show examples with code that might be useful.